# Find value of K?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

IF the number of ways of selecting *K* coupons out of an unlimited number of coupons bearing the letters A, T, M so that they cannot be used to spell to the word MAT is 93, then what is the value of *k*.

Comment: dont know from where to start

Comment: So what have you learnt about choosing things? Also, have you tried working out how many ways there would be of selecting $K$ coupons if $K=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: Your $K$ coupons must be missing at least one letter, else you'd be able to spell MAT.  So you either have one letter repeated $K$ times (and there are $3$ choices for which letter that is), or you have two letters.  How many ways can the latter occur?

Comment: Answer for this is given K= 5...Thanx Tad, I thought on the same lines..but couldnot write mathematical formula for it..plz help

Comment: we can solve M + A + T = K (distribute K objects among 3 persons namely M, A, T so that at least one of M, A, T gets no object)..

Answer (score 1):

MAT cannot be spelled if either the coupons of only one letter is chosen or the coupons of any two of them is chosen.

No. of ways to choose only one letter is $3C1 = 3$

No. Of way sin which coupons of any two of them is chosen is 
$3C2 (2^k -2)$
 Adding

$3C1 + 3C2 (2^k -2) = 93$.     (Given)

$2^k=32$
$K=5$.

Comment: The answer is not well written but is correct.